# Does anyone have experience with JacpFx?

Tags: javafx

I have a decant knowledge in Java and was developing small apps in JavaFx in the last three months or so. I'm currently doing some research about JavaFx application frameworks, since my next project will be bigger and more serious business app.

I like the idea behind [JacpFx](http://jacpfx.org/), but couldn't find any developing experiences with it, issues, developing speed or performance in that regard. Also, the last release was a year ago.

Basically, I'd be thankful for any comments in this regard. Also, on the JavaFx note, do you think that developing speed shouldn't suffer much if I choose to not use any framework at all? The application I'll develop is CRUD app, with big database, dynamic reports, basic business management app.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what are the downvotes for? If I somehow misplaced this question I'd be happy to know that :)

Comment: You're getting downvotes because the question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this forum. Specifically, it is not a "a practical, answerable problem", but is too general, broad, and is opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Application Framework will definitely help you to focus on adding value to your application instead of creating applications foundations.

There are a lot of application frameworks but nobody has compared them and has published a summary.

Quite difficult to estimate development velocity, I think that it's not the most important, other questions:

- is it inter-operable
- is it efficient (CPU & memory)
- is it simple to understand
- Is architecture will support project growth
- has it some support from community/developer

... etc